# ECDSA private key recovery

Tags: public-key, dsa, secp256k1

I have a bunch of signatures (1000) signed with ECDSA secp256k1 curve. I can verify all of them with the same public key.

I have studied attacks are performed against ECDSA signatures using known MSB or LSB of the nonce.

Is private key recovery possible if nonce $k$ value is of unknown length? None of the signatures have the same $k$ value.

Without private key knowledge can I alter valid signatures to sign my own messages?

Comment: What has *length* got to do with it? Usually $k$ is in a specified range, right? There would not be that many bit lengths possible if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: The attack's based on the bias on the nonce $k$. Even tiny bias is exploitable. My advice ( your second question's base) drop your key and start to use [Deterministic ECDSA](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6979.txt) by our Thomas Pornin as many coins migrated.